# Upgrade Sagepay "SERVER" Integration 2.23 to 3.00

Tags: php, protocols, upgrade, payment-gateway, opayo

Could someone please let me know how to Upgrade Sagepay `"SERVER" Integration` method from protocol 2.23 to 3.00. I can see some technical documents from various forums but are always focus to upgrading Sagepay `FORM Integration` method only. Am using SERVER method to send transactions to sagepay.

Help me what are the fields that I should add/change over my code(transaction array), Or if any specific document for SERVER method that you suggest is most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going from 2.23  to 3.00 using Server, the most basic change you can get away is changing the VPSProtocol value. You do need to be aware that a few extra fields will be returned in the post to your notificationURL, so you need to be able to ignore (or capture the values) as appropriate.

Changing to 3.00 will keep you trading ;-) and also give you access to a few more features....

Comment: When sending the Transaction POST to Sagepay, I en-counted an internal warning/notification from Sagepay something says "Signature mismatch"

"TAMPER WARNING! Signatures do not match for this Order. The Order was Cancelled. strMySignature=349C5BF4107273CBF198F77440146750 strVPSSignature=E4230A73EB14FD97CC99238F48973E59"

Comment: Or, should I update the XML template sagepay merchant's  account? Please advice.

Comment: That doesn't originate from Sage Pay. It is likely that you need to update the MD5 hash that you are checking the response from Sage Pay against. It should consist of: MD5 signature of the
concatenation of the values of:

{VPSTxId }+ VendorTxCode +
Status + TxAuthNo +
VendorName + AVSCV2 +
SecurityKey + AddressResult
+ PostCodeResult +
CV2Result + GiftAid +
3DSecureStatus + CAVV +
AddressStatus + PayerStatus
+ CardType + Last4Digits +
DeclineCode + ExpiryDate +
FraudResponse +
BankAuthCode

Comment: Also have a look at: https://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/21081/download-document/SERVER_Integration_and_Protocol_Guidelines_130515.pdf

Comment: Ric Blacow, Thanks a lot for your suggestion its done and functioning well. Great :)

Answer (score 0):

Guys who are seeking the same please replace the code like below on your notificationPage.php

FIND THIS ON YOUR CODE

```
$strMessage=$strVPSTxId . $strVendorTxCode . $strStatus . $strTxAuthNo . $strVendorName . $strAVSCV2 . $strSecurityKey 
                   . $strAddressResult . $strPostCodeResult . $strCV2Result . $strGiftAid . $str3DSecureStatus . $strCAVV
                   . $strAddressStatus . $strPayerStatus . $strCardType . $strLast4Digits ;
$strMySignature=strtoupper(md5($strMessage));
```

AND REPLACE WITH THE BELOW

```
$strMessage=$strVPSTxId . $strVendorTxCode . $strStatus . $strTxAuthNo . $strVendorName . $strAVSCV2 . $strSecurityKey 
                   . $strAddressResult . $strPostCodeResult . $strCV2Result . $strGiftAid . $str3DSecureStatus . $strCAVV
                   . $strAddressStatus . $strPayerStatus . $strCardType . $strLast4Digits . $strDeclineCode . $strExpiryDate 
                   . $strFraudResponse . $strBankAuthCode;
    $strMySignature=strtoupper(md5($strMessage));
```

THANKS TO Ric Blacow